# cant move turtle in turtlesim with key inputs

Tags: ros, turtlesim, turtlesim-node, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to go through the tutorial. I am on " Understanding ROS Topics". I can get the turtlesim open but when I try to move the turtle, nothing happens. No, keyinputs appear in the terminal. I am getting the following error in the "roscore" terminal.

```
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [IP_OF_TURTLEBOT]
```

I have looked around a lot and cannot find the answer. Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200402/cant-move-turtle-in-turtlesim-with-key-inputs/) by [mercury](https://answers.ros.org/users/21287/mercury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/163556/how-to-solve-couldnt-find-an-af_inet-address-for-problem/

You might also want to check [Network configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Name_resolution) page.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mercury](https://answers.ros.org/users/21287/mercury/) on 2015-01-05**:
Thanks, this lead me to the correct answer, I had to fix my IP andress